# Bootstrap toggle dropdown without making active menu item

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid black-back">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Judicial Workbench</a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Min/Mandatory Chart</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="pull-right white">
                <span>Welcome, Judge Mathis!</span>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right white">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search search"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li>
                                <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-block submitBtn">Submit</button>
                                </form>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog white settings"></span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

What this is attempting to accomplish is that when the user clicks the search icon a small search form drops down. All of that works except that my code then sets the search icon to be the acive menu item.

[See my screencast](http://screencast.com/t/G0JUc7PbTrvb)

What I want is for it to just drop down the search box and not change the active menu item.

[See my JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikemahony/L02qh2qw/)

The above JSFiddle seems to work properly and I have no idea why as it is a copy/paste of my actual code that you could see running in the screencast above. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: You just want to retain the background color of the search box right?

Answer (score 0):

When you click the button, it automatically adds the class `open` to it, which has another background color. To retain the default one, you can add this to your CSS:

```
.open a {
   background: initial !important;
}
```